# Merge a Git repository into another one keeping all the history

Tags: git, merge, repository

I've started developing project A. Then, at some point, I cloned A to another location (project B), so that other developers could also participate. I've then moved on developing project B only. Now, I would like to integrate all changes I've done in project B into project A while keeping the whole history of both projects. Basically, project A is an old state of project B, where B contains additional branches.

Comment: If `B` is a fork of `A`, `B` has the full history. Why would you go back and continue working on `A` only. What would be the difference between `A` and `B` then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both the project are virtually the same!

But to answer to your question, you can add ProjectB as remote to ProjectA and fetch all the branches and check whichever you want out!

With git you can get any repository to talk to any other repository using remotes!

Hope it helps! :)